# "Open Document" VS menu equivalent in Eclipse?

Tags: visual-studio, eclipse, ide

I am starting to use Eclipse for C++ developing after years with Visual Studio. I am used to right-click a filename in an include-Statement and then click "Open Document" to jump to this file. Does something like this exist in Eclipse CDT?

Thanks.

Comment: Try holding down Control and mouseover on the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Using the mouse: Ctrl + MouseClick
- Using the keyboard: `F3`

Both also work to jump to definition or declaration of a symbol.

Furthermore, you can use `Ctrl +Tab` to switch between a cpp file and its header. ("Toggle Source/Header")

The keyboard shortcuts are also shown in the context menu in the editor, there are many more very useful like `F4` for type hierarchy or Ctrl-Alt-H for Call Graph.

Eclipse also ships with alternative key bindings to be similar to Visual Studio or Emacs. (Window->Preferences->General->Keys ---> Scheme)